# SharePoint Warm Up Script failed for url

Tags: 2013, warm-up

My organization has 600 sites and subsites in 4 different site collection. We run Sharepoint Warm up Script at 3 am in the morning to make sure users all set to go at the morning. Recently i have been encountered with failed SharePoint Warm Up Script with 6-7 sites regularly. They Fail at 3 am in the morning and they fire off again at 8 am in the morning(for scheduler that has been scheduled to fire off).

Dont know why this is happening.

Here is the code :

[image]

Comment: need code or more details. Nobody knows what your 'warm up' script does

Comment: Is this something different than http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/109662/a-failure-was-reported-when-trying-to-invoke-a-service-applicationendpointfailu

Comment: No, may be related to that issue i have having with the managedmetadata svc

Comment: the site collection for which it is failing, did you check if those are locked or maxed out their quota? are all site collections in same web app alongwith other passing site collections?

Comment: I just checked it is failing on all 4 top level site collections including site for central admin.

Comment: it looks like permission issue , i am able to run same script without errors . try adding some error logs .

Comment: I have been running same code in my dev server with exact same system account, they have been populating fine. But i will agains cross check the permissions just to be sure.

Comment: can you suggest what permissions are required to run such scripts on the servers(i did configure this to start with)